# How to add the result of an "if" statement to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to Python, so I apologize for using any terminology incorrectly. I am trying to filter through a list of words, then add words that begin with "a" to a dictionary. But I am having trouble with adding the values after my `if` statement to the dictionary. My code is as follows:

```py
import sys
import re

text = ['Python','can','be','easy','to','pick','up','whether','you', 'are', 'a', 'first', 'time', 'programmer', 'or', 'you', 'are', 'experienced', 'with', 'other', 'languages']
filtered_text={}

#----  to filter words that begin with a ----
for x in text:
    if re.findall("^[aA]\w+",x):
        filtered_text.update(x)

    print(filtered_text)
```

Comment: So, what sort of trouble are you having?

Comment: `if result := re.findall("^[aA]\w+",x):` You should be able to use variable result in the if scope.

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you want a count each word starting in A/a?

Comment: @Golon That is not valid Python syntax. You may be thinking of [`:=`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) or the way almost every modern programming language that isn't Python works.

Comment: A dictionary entry is a key and a value. What dictionary do you actually want to end up with?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I see. I have edited my comment.

Comment: sorry, I do want a count, eventually. This is a practice problem I am working on and I'm trying to understand one step at a time.

Comment: We are also having hard time understand what you want to output to be. Please make the problem statement clear with examples.

Comment: for example, I would like:  are 2 , a  1. A count of the frequency of the words that begin with 'a'

Comment: @Rbcc please either accept the best answer and post new problem if you have any or just edit a question, but do not switch in between please. A good answer will depend on your FINAL goal.

Comment: @Rbcc Can you please check my answer?

Comment: @Rbcc Just 'a' or for all the characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure. But maybe you are looking for this?
It stores all the words that start with `a` in a dictionary with the word as a key and count as the value.

```
import sys
import re

text = ['Python','can','be','easy','to','pick','up','whether','you', 'are', 'a', 'first', 'time', 'programmer', 'or', 'you', 'are', 'experienced', 'with', 'other', 'languages']
filtered_text={}

#----  to filter words that begin with a ----
for x in text:
    if x[0].lower() == 'a':
        if x not in filtered_text:
            filtered_text[x] = 0
        filtered_text[x] += 1
            

print(filtered_text)
```

Comment: yes, like that. I'm sorry for the confusion

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solves your issue. @Rbcc

Answer (score 1):

Why to a dictionary? Words starting with "a" should be a key or value? if value, what you want key(s) to be? Here I'm adding it to a list:

```
text = ['Python','can','be','easy','to','pick','up','whether','you', 'are', 'a', 'first', 'time', 'programmer', 'or', 'you', 'are', 'experienced', 'with', 'other', 'languages']
filtered_text=[]

for element in text:
    if element[0] == 'a':
        filtered_text.append(element) 

print(filtered_text)
```

is this what You are looking for? If this is an output You are looking for and You need some explanations just let me know in comments.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add. This is part of a practise assignment I am working on and I was trying to work through one part at a time so that I could understand each step ( not sure if that is a good method to try). I would like to have the result as a key and add the value later.  If that makes sense

Comment: @Rbcc you should edit your question, and maybee start by tellng us you want a dummy value like None for each or the number of occurence.

Comment: okay, so You can make list first like in my example or other above. Result: ```['are', 'a', 'are']```. So you have "are" twice. Dictionares do not support duplicate keys. You can use: ```my_dict = dict.fromkeys(filtered_text, 0)``` - you're result after this will be: ```{'are': 0, 'a': 0}```. As far as I know You can't make dict with keys and no values. So we are setting all values to 0 for now, then you can change them

Answer (score 1):

If you want a counter then you could use `collections.Counter`:

```py
from collections import Counter

text = ['Python','can','be','easy','to','pick','up','whether','you', 'are', 'a', 'first', 'time', 'programmer', 'or', 'you', 'are', 'experienced', 'with', 'other', 'languages']

filtered_text = Counter([word for word in text if word[0].lower() == 'a'])

print(filtered_text)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'are': 2, 'a': 1})
```